# LinkedHashMap Memory leak In JDK 7

Tags: java, caching, memory-leaks, java-7, linkedhashmap

I wrote a LRU cache using LinkedHashMap. I use it cache some memory tables. Table size varies from several rows to thousands rows. In order to control the memory more precisely, I set max rows of cache instead of max tables. The cache run in a multiple thread context. I test the codes in JDK7 and JDK8. they have totally different results. In JDK7, it seems that Memory leak very fast. In JDK8, it run very stable without memory leak. Anyone can help on this? I can't believe JDK 7 has so serious bug!

Here is the code：

```
public class TableLRUCache<K>
{
    private String cacheName;
    private TableLRUCache.InternalMap container;

    public TableLRUCache(String cacheName, int cacheSize)
    {
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
        container = new TableLRUCache.InternalMap(cacheSize);
    }

    public synchronized TableWrapper get(K k)
    {
        TableWrapper result = (TableWrapper) container.get(k);
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.hit();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public synchronized TableWrapper put(K k, TableWrapper tableWrapper)
    {
        TableWrapper result = container.put(k, tableWrapper);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<K, TableWrapper>> it = container.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            if (container.totalRows <= container.maxRows)
            {
                break;
            }
            Map.Entry<K, TableWrapper> entry = it.next();
            if (!entry.getValue().isPersist())
            {
                //the table has not persistent, delete it later.
                continue;
            }
            it.remove();
            updateTableSurviveStatistic(entry.getValue());
            BaseTable deleteTable = entry.getValue().table;
            if (deleteTable != null)
            {
                container.totalRows -= deleteTable.getRows().size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public synchronized TableWrapper remove(K k)
    {
        TableWrapper result = container.remove(k);
        if (result != null)
        {
            updateTableSurviveStatistic(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void updateTableSurviveStatistic(TableWrapper tableWrapper)
    {
        //update statistic
    }

    public synchronized String statistic()
    {
        // get statistic
        return null;
    }

    public synchronized int getCacheSize()
    {
        return container.maxRows;
    }

    public synchronized int getUsedRows()
    {
        return container.totalRows;
    }

    public class InternalMap<K> extends LinkedHashMap<K, TableWrapper>
    {
        private int maxRows;
        private int totalRows = 0;

        public InternalMap(int cacheSize)
        {
            super(16, (float) 0.75, true);
            this.maxRows = cacheSize;
        }

        @Override
        public TableWrapper put(K key, TableWrapper tableWrapper)
        {
            TableWrapper old = this.remove(key);
            if (old != null)
            {
                totalRows -= old.table.getRows().size();
            }
            if (tableWrapper != null)
            {
                totalRows += tableWrapper.table.getRows().size();
            }
            return super.put(key, tableWrapper);
        }

        @Override
        public TableWrapper remove(Object key)
        {
            TableWrapper result = super.remove(key);
            if (result != null)
            {
                totalRows -= result.table.getRows().size();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing this wrong. You should have overridden `LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry()` and nothing else. See the Javadoc.

Comment: My case is a little complex. Overridden removeEldestEntry can not meet my requirements. I want to limit on the rows instead of tables. also some table if they are persisting, I can't remove them from cache. I am curious about why the code works find on JDK 8, but not JDK 7. what's the root cause? It is caused by my code or JDK?